# How to get data using a generic self init function then handle the callback (complete) separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, prototype

I have a component called `contentFetcher` which is responsible to get the content from the API:

```
'use strict';
import $ from 'jquery';
export default ContentFetch;

/*
  `element` is the element where you'd like to render the complete 
   callback
  `urlFeed` is the URL API
  `onComplete` is the callback (function)
*/
function ContentFetch(element, urlFeed, onComplete) {
    $.get({
        url: urlFeed,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: (data, responseText, jqXHR) => {
            ContentFetch.showData(element, data);
            if (jqXHR.status == 204) {
                ContentFetch.hideWidget(element);
            }
        },
        error: () => {
            ContentFetch.hideWidget(element);
        },
        complete: onComplete
    });
}

ContentFetch.showData = function(element, data) {
    $(element).html(data);
};

ContentFetch.hideWidget = function(element) {
    $(element).addClass('is-hidden');
};
```

At this moment I use this by importing `ContentFetch` and use it by calling:
`contentFetch(element, component.urlFeed, handleComplete);`

PS: Example of `handleComplete`is:
`const handleComplete =  function() { console.log('callback on complete yay'); };`

This works, but I'd like to refactor it to be more generic where `ContentFetcher` will just get the data and then handle the callback separately. I'd like to make `ContentFetcher` to be a self init component.
Can someone suggest me a good strategy for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "self init component"? Can you provide some other example component which "self init"?

Comment: Self initializing as in turning all elements with the default selector into components, such as:
`$(COMPONENT_SELECTOR).each(function(index, element) {
    return new ContentFetch(element);
});`

Comment: Still feel a bit confused on what you want. Can you try the refactor yourself first? It is easier to understand your intention if some refactor work is done, and some specific problem is raised.